# Port forwarding with port 443: The IP address is not in the same subnet with LAN IP address

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm running a small website on a raspberry pi.

I can access the website over the internet on port 80. To do this, I had to configured my router (Tp-link Archer C50) to forward traffic on port 80 to the raspberry pi. I have done the same with port 22 to enable SSH.

Now I'm trying to do the same with port 443, which in my understanding should allow the raspberry pi to serve the website with SSL. However, when trying to do so, I get the following error that I do not understand:

```
The IP address is not in the same subnet with LAN IP address. Please input another one.
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what is says.
The IP-address (of the PI I presume) you specified when defining the port-forward isn't in the ip-range of your local LAN.
Maybe you made a typo in the IP-address ?
The line should look exactly as for the 80 and 22 port-forwards, except for the different port-number of course.

Comment: I was using the autocomplete, trusting it like an idiot. I was certain I was using the right one..but..the autocomplete was wrong.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :-)